# How to make JS and CSS compatible with IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

Our company develops ERP and CRM, and so far our products support IE and Firefox. Now we want to support Chrome, Safari and even Opera. Is there any comprehensive materials that introduce browser compatibility of JS and CSS? thks!

Comment: I think you've won 80% of the battle already by conquering IE, the rest will be easy.

Comment: What Madmartigan says is true in fact. JavaScript developers classify modern browsers into 2 major categories, Internet Explorer only in first group, and all other browsers in another group. What's OK with FF, 99% is OK with Chrome, Opera, etc. There are few tiny differences but when you face them (or IF you), you can easily Google for solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any comprehensive materials that introduce browser
>   compatibility of JS and CSS?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)
http://html5test.com/
http://caniuse.com/

"Comprehensive" can change overnight, but there is a great deal of information available.

If your products work for the latest version of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera will work without major flaws **most of the time**. If your markup is invalid, you are using many vendor-specific extensions, or you are using cutting-edge features, this may not be the case.

Comment: This table is outdated! Windows Phone HAVE media query support! http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/03/22/targeting-mobile-optimized-css-at-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: Too bad, it used to be a great resource. I'll update the links.

Comment: @Ai_boy - Too bad it doesn't work anywhere else and no on uses a Windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

theres the mozilla dev-center that has a great [CSS-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_Reference) and [JavaScript-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript)reference. Every entry has information about browser compatibility.

For a quick overview, you cauld also take a look at [caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com/) ([CSS](http://www.caniuse.com/#cats=CSS) and [JavaScript](http://www.caniuse.com/#cats=JS_API)) that provides simple tabular lists for the different features.

Answer (score 1):

I've been coding the front-end for over a decade and a half now, and things seem to get better over time in regards to cross-browser compatibility. I've found that if I write and test my code using Firefox, most everything will work flawlessly on Chrome, Opera, Safari and the only thing you'll end up having to debug would be MSIE. 10 years ago I would have told you to code and test using MSIE and debug your code in the end with Netscape.

But yeah, if you follow this, you'll find it easier to make all your scripting and markup fully cross-browser compatible with no bugs at all. Enter IE9, of course, a different monster altogether.

Comment: Ahh the `<table>` days, filled with `spacer.gif`s and saturated `<font>`s in Comic Sans. Glad it's over.

Comment: Tee hee hee, yeah you remember those days. They were simple days, but interactivity was a pain in the rear end to introduce, while keeping it all fully cross-browser compatible.

One of my greatest feats came with creating a virtual iframe before mozilla supported the iframe. Worked marvelously, so much so, I kind also used it much like we use AJAX nowadays, its was killer for its time. Created awesome interfaces due to the ability to load data on the fly.

Comment: My boss still says "Java Rollovers". Show some support here: http://www.saveie6.com/

Comment: PNG transparency in IE6. BLEH! Hell all my new code still works on IE6, the interfaces look terrible though, since I am not making them compatible with the IE6 PNG bug.

Comment: Yeah pngs are a joke, animated clipart is where it's at. And music playing when you open the page... One of my favorite IE6 bugs is that it submits the innerHTML of `<button>`s instead of the `value`. In reality, I'm still using a lot of "safe" hacks that I learned while coding for IE6, and most of my current work is usable in IE6. Right now, IE8 is the new bane.

Comment: Actually, IE8 I have no problem with. Hit me with IE9 then we gotta duke it out!

Comment: Haha embeded midi and animated GIFs! Classic. Even in this day in age, I still see some company websites with this style of design, just wow! Yeah midi was the norm, try loading a wav file at 300 baud! Of course, I'm exaggerating the modem speed a bit here :P